# How to use an argument with question mark in methods have keyword arguments

Tags: ruby

How to use an argument with question mark in methods have keyword arguments?

```
def foo(arg?:)
  p arg? # ERROR
end

foo(arg?: true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Just confirmed it, you can do `foo(arg?: true)`

**Original:**

I'm not sure that you can have a "?" in a kwarg. You could try making the method have one input arg which is a hash, and then I think you could do

```
def foo(arg)
  p arg[:"arg?"]
end

foo(:"arg?" => true)
```

The quotes *may* not be necessary, I'd have to open up the console to check. In which case:

```
foo(arg?: true)
```

### Update 2

Sergio has rightly called out the fact that I'm *not* using a key word argument (kwarg) in this solution, instead I'm passing a single, regular argument which *I know* needs to be a hash with a `:arg?` key. This is commonly referred to as an options hash. This is what people did before the ruby language added support for kwargs (or so I'm told :).

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that. Parameter names can't have question or exclamation marks. Only method names can have them.

As John mentions, you should be able to use the good old options hash. Although, in this case `foo(arg?: true)`, `arg?: true` is a key-value pair in a hash, not a keyword argument. Big difference (with options hash, you don't get effortless required parameters and typo protection, for example).

Comment: but methods with question mark may be passed as argument, arent they?

Comment: @marmeladze: "methods"? I don't think so. They're reduced to their value and that's what is passed. Of course, you can get a hold of a Method object, but at this point it doesn't have question marks either.

Comment: @marmeladze: example?

Comment: sorrry, i was mistaken. i first tought about sth like `'foo'.respond_to? :include?` but then realized this is not a method definition - just call -))

Comment: As @marmeladze comments, we can use question marks as keyword arguments (not raise runtime errors), and can give a hash as keywords arguments like `hash = { arg?: true }` `foo(hash)` .
I can understand there is a big difference as you say, but I'm confused.

Comment: @yushirota: your code clearly demonstrates that you _can't_ use question marks in keyword arguments. So I'm not sure what you mean. (To reiterate once again: kwargs != options hash)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev one still can pass `hash = {arg?: true}` as double-splatted keyword argument: `def blah(**kw); puts kw; end; blah(**hash)`.

Comment: @yushirota in `'foo'.respond_to? :include?`, `:include?` is being passed as the value for the `respond_to?` method's argument. Symbol's can have question marks, and `:include?` is a symbol

Comment: @mudasobwa: aight, one can _pass_, but what good is it, if you can't __define__ a method with a parameter named `arg?`. Your example with `**kwargs` is indistinguishable from options hash. Doesn't get any kwargs benefits. In fact, the only thing it adds is more complex syntax.

Comment: @yushirota when you use a keyword param it gets converted to a variable. `arg?` can't be a variable because variables can't have question marks. It can be a string, symbol, or method name, but nothing else.

Comment: oh, I was mistaken. Just define a method has kwargs using `arg?` (with question marks), raised an method definition error. I assumed we can define kawrgs with question marks.